# TransactionRequiredException when trying to insert data into database with Java

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I am trying to insert data into a database using a code looking something like this:

```
Query query=em.createNativeQuery("insert into tab1 (col1, col2) values ('val1', 'val2')");
int result=query.executeUpdate();
```

but it throws a TransactionRequiredException. What is that?

Comment: You need a transaction ... like the exception says! Any JPA docs would tell you how to have one

Comment: I've also tried to surround my code with entityManager.getTransaction().begin() and entityManager.getTransaction().commit() but I've gotten another exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()

Comment: and since you dont define your `persistence.xml` then what do you expect people to tell you that JPA docs wouldn't ? http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_2/jpa/persistence.html#transaction_jta  It is you that has selected to use JTA transactions after all, so you must know how to use them

Answer (score 1):

Exception is self explanatory and already multiple solutions given on stack overflow.

You need to start session (Transaction) before doing any insert/update/delete operation.
If you are using spring, then you can use @Transactional Attribute Otherwise programatically create/close transaction.

Please check.
[Transaction required exception JPA / Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29601028/transaction-required-exception-jpa-spring)

Comment: I've just inserted @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) above my method but it underlines both Transactional and Propagation

Comment: I've also tried to surround my code with entityManager.getTransaction().begin() and entityManager.getTransaction().commit() but I've gotten another exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()

Comment: Did you define TransactionManager? What does it mean underlines. You can directly use it with default propagation type like @Transactional()

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found out that I had a property in my class looking like this:

```
@Resource
javax.transaction.UserTransaction userTransaction;
```

so the correct way to perform the insertion was:

```
userTransaction.begin();
Query query=em.createNativeQuery("insert into tab1 (col1, col2) values ('val1', 'val2')");
int result=query.executeUpdate();
userTransaction.commit();
```